# How to set DB2 SQL ANSI Mode

Tags: db2, db2-400, ansi-sql

I have a php project developed up on Ubuntu Intel 64 Bit machine. It uses the DB2 as database. Now client going to deploy it on IBM I Series Server.  So I gave him exported Schema (by db2look command).

```
db2look -d MYDATABASE -a -e -o mydatabase.sql
```

But he have problem in importing As exported schema have some keyword not supported on DB2 IBM version. He point out on `octets` keyword. But definitely more could be there. So he want us to convert our schema to some MySQL or ANSI Mode. But I did not found any tutorial to convert DB2 schema or change Mode.

I am very new to DB2, Any all my DB exposure to MySQL database only. If anybody have idea about this ?

Comment: Can you give the output of the error? are you exporting from db2 for I, or from any other kind of DB2 (i.e. luw)?

Comment: "*to convert our schema to some MySQL Mode*" - why do you think you can use MySQL syntax on a DB2 server? And "MySQL mode" is far from being "ANSI mode".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I understand that But it is client suggestion to use MySQL or ANSI Mode. I did not have idea If these mode exists and how they can be enabled.

Comment: @AngocA, that part I am not involved As client own technical team imported DB SQL File and face problems, He just inform us that He face problem due to different mode. Only thing he hints out is `octets` Which could be disabled in his IBM i series server.

Comment: @AngocA, for your second question, I am not completely confirmed , But it should be DB2 IBM Version not luw version, Because why that client force us to see differences between db2 linux version vs db2 ibm version. While at local development machine we already using luw version.

Comment: Your problem is not clear, thus it is difficult to help you. BTW, there are different DB2 flavors: for LUW (Linux, UNIX and Windows) for i (old AS/400) and for z/OS

Comment: Firstly, the `OCTETS` and `CHARACTERS` in the character data type length specification is indeed a part of the ANSI SQL 2008 standard, so your client's request to suppy ANSI-compatible code is already fulfilled. Secondly, there are far more differences between the DB2 LUW and System i versions than the syntactic sugar. If the target application platform is System i (AS/400) you should not be developing on DB2 LUW.

Comment: @mustaccio If any DB2 mode or variant have problem with 'octets' during import. Because it could be possible that client already set to some other mode.

Comment: @mustaccio, AngocA, I am not confirmed with OS, Still I have only information of Machine which is IBM Iseries 7.2. I need to get back at client to get OS information.

Comment: IBM i 7.2 *is* the operating system. DB2 for i is part of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

IBM has a manual

- IBM DB2 for i porting guide DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows to the IBM i platform
  (Updated June 2014)

http://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/servers/enable/site/db2_porting_i.html

Are you using Zend for your PHP by chance?

Zend is supported on the IBM i:
http://www.zend.com/en/solutions/modernize-ibm-i

Also Zend picked up the slack when MySQL support for IBM i was dropped by Oracle
http://www.zend.com/en/solutions/modernize-ibm-i/ibm-i-product/dbi

Zend's DBi product includes the IBMDB2I storage engine allowing php/MySQL apps to run on the IBM i and utilize DB2 for i as the database.

Comment: Application in Zend Framework 2. I did not know If they going to use Zend Server at there ?

Comment: What version of DB2 for i?  (Note OS and DB2 version are the same for IBM i OS and DB2 for i)  According to the porting manual I mentioned, beginning at v6.1 IBM started adding tolerance of syntax and statements not supported; and they indicate a willingness to accept samples of syntax that could be ignored.

Comment: Previous comment above indicates i 7.2.